# plone.app.theming display themed error pages which get markup from sub requests

Tags: themes, plone, diazo

We're using plone.app.theming with some rules that use external content to build our theme. e.g. we have a view named "standard-page-elements" and a number of rules that copy content from it like

```
 <copy attributes="*" theme="/html" content="/html" href="@@standard-page-elements" />
```

This results is a sub-request being sent to Plone for standard-page-elements in the current context.  This all works great.

I'm running into a problem theming error pages.  In particular requests for a path with a number of folders where one of the parent folders doesn't exist e.g.

/misspelt/my_page

This results in a sub-request which itself generates a not found error and then you end up with an unformatted error page and a traceback in your logs.

Our Plone site is set-up for multiple sub-sites such that the public home page of each sub-site is actually an object one level down (/plone/my_site_1, /plone/my_site_2) all configured with Apache virtual hosts and Zope virtual host monster.

Essentially what I want to do is use the sub-sites standard-page-elements view for error pages but I can't figure out a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just pushed some changesets for plone.app.theming that should mean `href="/@@standard-page-elements"` is now resolved against the navigation root rather than the plone site root. You'll need to conditionally use one or the other depending on something present in the not found page.

I think `href="@@standard-page-elements"` probably should resolve from the closest context rather than the supplied url (which would also fix things for you) but I need to think more about where and how I can fix that.

Comment: Great.  I'd actually tested that same change locally and was going to suggest a patch.  I can now put some logic in my rules for error pages to use the absolute path.  One way to get the closest context is from the Zope request object.  `request.other['PARENTS'][0]` will do it I think.